# Responsive collapsible menu for mobile, using Bootstrap class list-group

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a very simple, fast-loading, easy to read and responsive design for my website. I'm using Bootstrap's list-group class for the left hand navigation, and I've been unable to find a way to make that collapsible for mobile/smaller devices. Also, my top nav disappears when I reduce the screen too much. Should I just scrap the design and start over? I'm generally happy with it except for the lack of mobile compatibility.

http://www.taniarascia.com/acordeondeteclas

This is my first time trying to use something like this for help, any feedback would be appreciated.

```
<div class="list-group">
<a href="intro.html" class="list-group-item">The Basics</a>
```

Is the way I'm making my left hand navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Your menu:

```
<div id="sidebar" class="list-group">
    <a class="list-group-item collapse-toggle head1">Learn Piano Accordion</a>
    <div id="menu" class="hidden-tablet collapse">
        <a class="list-group-item" href="intro.html">The Basics</a>
        <a class="list-group-item" href="types.html">Types of Accordions</a>
        <a class="list-group-item" href="musictheory.html">Music Theory</a>
        <a class="list-group-item" href="scales.html">Scales, Thirds and Sixths</a>
        <a class="list-group-item" href="chords.html">Major, Minor and 7th Chords</a>
        <a class="list-group-item" href="keys.html">Keys and Chord Progressions</a>
        <a class="list-group-item" href="tutorials.html">Tutorials</a>
        <a class="list-group-item" href="adornos.html">Adornos</a>
        <a class="list-group-item" href="basses.html">Basses</a>
        <a class="list-group-item" href="bands.html">Bands with Piano Accordion</a>
        <a class="list-group-item" href="misc.html">Miscellaneous</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.collapse-toggle').on('click', function(){
    $('#menu').collapse('toggle');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/te9hL/)

**UPDATE:**
To hide the menu when using mobile devices you can add a jQuery function to check the actual size of the screen and do an action when lower than X (in this case 480).

JS:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    var windowSize = $(window).width();
    if(windowSize < 480) {
        $('#menu').collapse('hide');
    } else {
        $('#menu').collapse('show');
    }
});
```

[Fiddle Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/te9hL/5/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response! I was able to get that to work. However, I just have one issue - I want the menu to be visible until a certain width - is there any way to make the JS to only activate at a certain screen resize? I've been trying to look for it on my own but haven't had any specific luck.

Here's how it looks as is:
http://www.taniarascia.com/acordeondeteclas/fiddle.html

Thanks again.